# ¿Cuál podría ser una palabra cariñosa para describir a una niña con actitudes de niño?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término, españa

Hace tiempo, en mi época álgida de estudiar japonés, una de las cosas que me dio por hacer fue traducir directamente desde este idioma los primeros tomos del manga de [Candy Candy](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Candy_Candy). Uno de los puntos donde tuve problemas fue con la traducción de la palabra おてんば (otenba) que, al igual que el inglés *[tomboy](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tomboy)* (*"a girl who behaves in a manner usually considered boyish"*, palabra que se usó en la traducción inglesa), se puede usar para designar a una "niña poco femenina".

[image: Candy Candy: "otenba-san"]
<sup>Archibald se despide con un beso de Candy llamándola "otenba-san".</sup>

Esta palabra se puede usar tanto en su versión en inglés como en japonés como una palabra cariñosa, para designar a aquellas niñas que prefieren los juegos y las actitudes más propias de los niños. Recuerdo que me quedé un poco confuso, porque la palabra que se me ocurría era *marimacho* ("mujer que en su corpulencia o acciones parece hombre"), pero se refiere a mujeres y hace referencia a la forma física al igual que al comportamiento, y no me suena como una palabra cariñosa. En algunas traducciones he visto que usan simplemente *chiquilla*, perdiendo la traducción esa connotación de niña vivaracha y con energía.

Al final un amigo mío que también se dedica a las traducciones desde el japonés me recomendó usar *fierecilla*, lo cual me pareció una solución muy elegante dado que recoge el espíritu indomable del personaje y es un término que está en el punto justo intermedio entre lo tierno y lo punzante, según quién y cómo lo pronuncie. Y así se quedó. Sin embargo, sigo preguntándome si no habría habido un término más adecuado que no diera tantos rodeos. Así pues, **¿existe un término en español que defina a las niñas que se comportan más como niños, y que sea de uso cariñoso?**

Nota: me encanta la frase de ejemplo que me ha dado el traductor de Google, dado que pasa lo mismo en español con *[nenaza](http://dle.rae.es/?id=QNvenrv)*:

> It's still cute for a girl to be a tomboy, but a terrible insult to call a boy a sissy.

Comment: "It's still cute for a girl to be a tomboy".. que? Como de que "cute"? También en inglés es una ofensa llamar a una mujer "tomboy" o "dyke"

Comment: Acabo de encontrar esto: [La polémica pregunta de Trivial sobre la hija **'marimacho'** de Ned Stark](https://verne.elpais.com/verne/2016/01/27/articulo/1453903813_495900.html)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mis propuestas: "**varonera**" (no es cariñosa, pero tampoco necesariamente despectiva, sino más bien neutra: *Es un poco varonera / Es medio varonera*), o "**diablilla**" (si bien este epíteto hace referencia a que la niña es traviesa, si suponemos que una nena suele ser más tranquila que un varón, podríamos entender que su eventual naturaleza movediza la hace menos femenina que el común de las nenas). (Nota: En alguna entrevista, recuerdo claramente a Borges referise a los niños en general como "diablillos". En verdad, no creo que le gustaran mucho o que les tuviera mucha paciencia...)

Comment: "Diablilla" no está nada mal. :)

Comment: @CarlosAlejo Es bastante simpática, a decir verdad.

Comment: I gave the bounty to **diablilla**, but I like my answer better.  (Well, I would, wouldn't I?  It's my answer.)  Unfortunately I can't give myself the bounty.

Answer (score 8):

Yo añado a la extensiva lista que tenemos ya la menos oída [virago](http://dle.rae.es/?id=bsG0DSu)

> **virago**
>
> *Del lat. virāgo, -ĭnis.*
>
> 1. f. Mujer varonil.

Es muy probable que tengas que explicar el significado de esta palabra a tu audiencia. Por otro lado, al ser usada de forma menos frecuente no creo que tenga asociadas algunas de las connotaciones negativas (tipo, "ser poco femenina", "ser demasiado X" ) que tienen algunos de los otros términos.

Por cierto, que esta palabra en inglés tiene un amplio rango de significados (que no recoge la entrada del DRAE)

> a woman of great stature, strength, and courage ([merriam-webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/virago))

Interesante esa asociación tamaño-estatura (a menos que aquí *stature* se refiera a *importancia*, que no creo) y fuerza (no aclara si física o de carácter) y coraje. Esta definición me hace pensar por ejemplo en el personaje de "Brienne of Tarth" de Juego de Tronos, juzgada más por su apariencia y tamaño que por su habilidad y valor.

> A virago is a woman who demonstrates exemplary and heroic qualities.([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virago))

Esta entrada cita a Juana de Arco, aunque la imagen del artículo enlazado a mi me hizo pensar en personajes del cómic como Wonder Woman. Interesante que el artículo explica

> The word *virago* has almost always had an association with cultural **gender transgression**.[...]
>
> The word *virago* could also be used disparagingly, to imply that a virago was not excellent or heroic, but was **instead violating cultural norms**. Thus *virago* **joined pejoratives such as termagant, mannish, amazonian and shrew to demean women who acted aggressively or like men**."

que enfatiza las muchas connotaciones negativas que tienen estos términos por referirse a las féminas más por salirse del rol que les establece la sociedad que por sus actos o los logros/consecuencias de los mismos.

Y de paso (segunda posibilidad)

> **[amazona](http://dle.rae.es/?id=2GzauN2)**
>
> 2. f. Mujer de apariencia o carácter fuerte y combativo.

Aunque de nuevo apariencia y carácter van unidos en la definición, no veo connotaciones negativas (tipo *demasiado grande/alta*, *demasiado agresiva*, etc.)

Volviendo de nuevo a *virago* (o sus definiciones en otros medios)

> 1. a loud-voiced, ill-tempered, scolding woman; shrew.
> 2. Archaic. a woman of strength or spirit.
>
> [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/virago)

que destaca de nuevo el contraste entre las connotaciones peyorativas que puede tener el término en cuando a referirse a mujeres de carácter *excesivamente* violento o malo y una mujer de gran fuerza de carácter.

Entiendo que `amazona` no se adapta del todo bien (y aparte tiene otras acepciones más usadas, como "mujer que monta a caballo") y `virago` es un término un poco oscuro, pero por lo menos en español parecen carecer de las connotaciones negativas que tienen algunos de los otros términos usados más frecuentemente.

Answer (score 6):

Al menos en Aragón es habitual la palabra *chicazo* con este sentido: una niña a la que gustan cosas, o tiene actitudes, consideradas tradicionalmente propias de niños. No es una palabra peyorativa, se puede usar perfectamente incluso con un matiz positivo. Por ejemplo:

> Mi hija Elena es un chicazo.

Significa que a Elena, por ejemplo, le gusta jugar al fútbol y la ropa sin puntillas ni lacitos.

> Yo de pequeña era un poco chicazo.

Significa que cuando era pequeña me gustaba jugar con los chicos, correr, tirarme por el suelo...

Naturalmente, no entro en si hoy día consideraríamos correcto o no decir que determinados comportamientos son propios de un sexo u otro.

Answer (score 5):

Como palabra algo menos ofensiva que "marimacho", a veces he oído (sureste de España) usar "**machota**":

> **[machota](http://dle.rae.es/?id=NnnfGOn)**
>
> 1. f. coloq. Mujer hombruna, marimacho.
> 2. f. *P. Rico.* Mujer garrida y lozana.

El uso viene a ser el mismo que "machote" pero en niñas.

La menor carga ofensiva viene porque "machota" se asocia semánticamente con "machote", que se suele usar en un contexto desenfadado e incluso positivo para el niño. Ejemplos:

> Para niño: *Te has terminado toda la comida, ¡estás hecho un machote!*
> Para niña: *Te has terminado toda la comida, ¡estás hecha una machota!*

Mientras que "marimacho" se asocia semánticamente con "maricón", que (como espero estemos todos de acuerdo) es tremendamente ofensivo.

Comment: He encontrado [un uso de "machota" en el CREA](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?visualizar?tipo1=5&tipo2=0&iniItem=2&ordenar1=0&ordenar2=0&FID=210217\016\C000O21022017165549345.1172.1168&desc={B}+{I}+machota{|I},+en+todos+los+medios,+en+{I}CREA+{|I}+{|B}{BR}&tamVen=1&marcas=0#acierto2) que es tremendamente educativo. :)

Comment: @walen - perdón, será el cansancio.  Ahí va otro intento.

Comment: Sería mejor incluir el país donde has oído el término, para saber dónde se puede usar el término que propones. Pero más importante: ¿Se puede usar para niñas, o sólo para adultas?  La definiciones que incluyes hablan de "mujer".

Answer (score 3):

En Venezuela, o al menos en el círculo social donde yo me crié, utilizamos `Macha` (aunque realmente no es una palabra) para referirnos a este concepto de la manera menos peyorativa posible.

> — Ella vestía ropa de varón y llevaba el cabello corto, lo cual ha hacía parecer algo **macha**.

Sin embargo, puede ser mal visto si se utiliza con alguien con quien no se tenga la suficiente confianza.

El modo despectivo sería `Machorra` o `Marimacha` pero estos serían mal vistos ¡incluso cuando exista confianza con la persona!

> — ¡Eres *burda* de **machorra**!

Curiosamente, en Venezuela no utilizamos el término `Maricón` de manera cotidiana, lo reducimos a `Marico`, aunque en otros países comúnmente se utilice la forma femenina `Marica`  o `Mariquita` (incluso en varones) y reservamos `Marica`  para mujeres exclusivamente.

> — Ese *chamo* sí es **marico**.
>
> — ¡*Épale*, **marica**!, ¿cómo está la *vaina*?

Aún más curioso es que si bien `Marico` se puede usar para referirse a un varón con características afeminadas o a un homosexual de manera peyorativa, `Marica` en las mujeres no tiene mayor peso ¡y definitivamente no significa lo mismo que su contraparte masculina!

Cabe destacar que en Venezuela cotidianamente utilizamos `Marico` para referirnos a amigos cercanos y no tiene ninguna intención denigrante.

> — ¿Qué hubo, **marico**, todo *fino*?

Como verás, dado que las culturas hispánicas históricamente han sido en exceso patriarcales y homofóbicas, realmente no hay una palabra que no sea despectiva en nuestra lengua para referirnos a una persona que no actúe de acuerdo a los estándares "aceptados" de su sexo biológico.

Por supuesto es cuestión de cambiar la forma en que ciertas palabras y actitudes son vistas más que de inventar palabras nuevas.

Comment: Según veo en el diccionario de americanismos, hay que tener mucho cuidado con la palabra _[macha](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=macha)_.   En México, Guatemala y Cuba significa "lesbiana" y es despectivo. En Guatemala, El Salvador, Puerto Rico y Bolivia significa lo mismo que "marimacho" y es también despectivo. En Nicaragua, Puerto Rico también, Colombia, Venezuela, Bolivia (imagino que según la zona) y con menos frecuencia en Perú sí puede significar "valiente, atrevida", y sería una palabra válida. Pero lo dicho, habría que tener cuidado con las acepciones en otros países.

Comment: Muy buena información, gracias por el dato. Una consulta: para los modismos que incluí en mi respuesta, ¿debería añadir hipervínculos a fuentes que los describan, como hiciste en el caso de "macha" en el Diccionario de Americanismos?

Comment: Normalmente suele ser una muy buena idea documentar las respuestas lo máximo posible usando hipervínculos. Cuantos más enlaces pongas, mejor. Eso sí, procura copiar de los enlaces las partes más importantes (esto es, argumenta tu respuesta con algo de información y deja el enlace para que quien quiera pueda consultar el tema más en profundidad).

Comment: @CarlosAlejo - pero no son imprescindibles en una respuesta como esta.

Comment: Javier, ¿se podría modificar para niña?  ¿Machita, mariquita, etc.?

Answer (score 3):

Acá en Argentina decimos:

> Varonera.
>
> Machona.
>
> Masculina.
>
> Marimacho.

Comment: ¿Dónde es acá? Mejor hazlo explícito para quien no te conozca :)

Comment: No creí que fuera necesario, ¿No aparece esa información en mi perfil?, en todo caso soy de Argentina, Resistencia Chaco.

Answer (score 1):

Voy a proponer, a ver qué opinan:

> Es una niña **no muy niña**

o quizás

> Es una niña un tanto **andrógina** (Drae: "Dicho de una persona: De rasgos externos que no se corresponden definidamente con los propios de su sexo"; cf. inglés: *androgynous*)

Lo que creo que estas opciones tienen es que

- son universales -- se pueden usar en cualquier país o región
- son términos neutros, que no van a ofender

*Quizás por el momento el español oficial no haya ajustado este término todavía, en paralelo con el inglés, pero creo que será necesaria esta evolución dentro de pocos años. La aceptación de la fluidez de género va en aumento, y el lenguaje se ajusta de acuerdo a las necesidades de comunicación.*

Comment: Lo malo de la segunda es que se entiende más como que tiene rasgos físicos de niño, más que actitud de niño. La primera opción podría ser una opción válida.

Comment: Ayer, hablando con mi hijo de 14 años, describí a una muchacha como *un tanto andrógina*, y me preguntó qué es eso; a mí se me dificulta dar definiciones, así que dije, "Es lo contrario de ser una niña princesa," y captó en seguida el concepto.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo - Interesante.  En inglés he visto que el término se usa para cualquier característica, no sólo el aspecto físico.  Creo que no soy yo nada más.  Echa un ojo a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Androgyny.

Comment: Claro, pero mira por ejemplo el caso del cómic del que hablo. [El personaje de Candy](http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/wikiseriesjaponesas/images/f/fc/Candy20.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20160901143001&path-prefix=es) no puede tener rasgos físicos más femeninos (se representa como una niña muy guapa). Yo en español entiendo la androginia como algo físico, por eso no veo ese término aplicado al personaje. Un personaje andrógino podría ser Mulán cuando se hace pasar por hombre, por ejemplo.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo - Yo estoy buscando una palabra que funcione en una variedad de contextos, no solo el cómic y el personaje que planteaste. // Quizás por el momento el español oficial no haya ajustado este término todavía, en paralelo con el inglés, pero creo que será necesaria esta evolución dentro de pocos años.  La aceptación de la fluidez de género va en aumento, y el lenguaje se ajusta de acuerdo a las necesidades de comunicación.

Answer (score 1):

Aunque llego tarde a esta contestación, podría agregar — con ánimo de aportar al espectro de respuestas leídas— que la manera que conozco (en la región norte de Argentina) usada para referirse a una niña que se sale del canon aceptable del comportamiento "femenino" esperado, es describirla con el adjetivo de "india". Así se dice de una muchachita (enérgica e indómita) que es

> re- (o muy) ***india***

La encuentro como una acepción sorprendentemente amable (muchas veces oída de boca de los propios padres, o de las mismas personas que definen su pasado brioso y no-convencional) para resaltar características de especial determinación, energía, rusticidad, valentía, bravura, o algún otro valor normalmente connotado en un varón.

Lo destaco además porque es a la vez un buen ejemplo del término —sinónimo de aborigen americano—, no usado con el sentido peyorativo que en otras ocasiones puede cargar.